# Why Magento redirect my custom controller to "customer/account/login/"

Tags: magento, redirect, controllers

I created my controller

```
<modules>
    <Articul_Registration>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Articul_Registration>
</modules>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <registration>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Articul_Registration</module>
                <frontName>registration</frontName>
            </args>
        </registration>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

And controller file

```
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
class Articul_Registration_RegistrationController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
       echo("Nice!");
   }
}
```

When I go to

```
www.sitename/registration
```

Magento is redirecting me to

```
www.sitename/customer/account/login
```

Why is this happening and how do I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...

```
    require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
    class Articul_Registration_RegistrationController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
    {
       public function registrationAction()
       {
           echo("Nice!");
       }
    }

/**
     * Action predispatch
     *
     * Check customer authentication for some actions
     */
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        // a brute-force protection here would be nice

        parent::preDispatch();

        if (!$this->getRequest()->isDispatched()) {
            return;
        }

        $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
        $openActions = array(
            'create',
            'login',
            'logoutsuccess',
            'forgotpassword',
            'forgotpasswordpost',
            'resetpassword',
            'resetpasswordpost',
            'confirm',
            'confirmation',
            'registration',
        );
        $pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $openActions) . ')/i';

        if (!preg_match($pattern, $action)) {
            if (!$this->_getSession()->authenticate($this)) {
                $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
            }
        } else {
            $this->_getSession()->setNoReferer(true);
        }
    }
```

Basically you don't want to use indexAction() because this is already defined in the parent controller, and because you using registration as your URL.   You'll want to navigate to
yourdomain.com/customer/registration

I didn't test this, but should get you going on the right path.

Comment: Glad to hear!  Note the important thing here is that I added "registration" to the list of open actions in the preDispatch method.   that tells magento not to redirect for that action.

Comment: @espradley doesn't work for me until I replace parent::preDispatch(); with Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::preDispatch(); as suggested here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18223358/1078641